# Email clients with GPG for linux, windows and android

Tags: windows, linux, android, gnupg, email-client

I need Your help. Im looking for some email client with GPG to use under linux, windows and android. Important for me is that, when I marked email as read under eg. linux it is marked as well under windows and android (synchronization). For now Im using gmail web interface, but I would to use GPG.

Linux and windows mention earlier are on one machine (I have linux and windows on my laptop and phone with android).

Answer (score 4):

Under Linux and Windows, you could use **Mozilla Thunderbird** with the [Enigmail](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/enigmail/) add-on that allows to sign and encrypt messages (and will work the best if you don´t use HTML formated messages).

For Android, **K-9** works very well. Although I've not used any GPG feature with it, it seems that [APG](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.thialfihar.android.apg&hl=en) offers a nice integration with K-9.

Comment: Once more: I'm not deleting my messages, so important for me is when I read some msg in one email client, they are also mark as read in other email clients. Have Thunderbird and K9 this feature?

Comment: That depends on the protocol you're using, if you're using IMAP, everything's fine with all relevant email clients (Thunderbird definitely is). Using POP3 this isn't possible, switch to IMAP instead which every reasonable email service provider offers. Gmail offers IMAP, so you will not have any problems with that.